# TFS 2013 admin page blank

Tags: tfs-web-access

After updating from TFS 2010 to TFS 2013 update 4 the web access tool isn't showing any of the Administration features.
I repaired TFS 2013 without any luck.The strange thing is I can see all requests to static content throw 500 server error even though all of the scripts are there.
IE throws this exception
**Loading Presentation/Scripts/TFS/TFS.Extensions failed, here are the modules that depend on it:** 
Firebug shows the following when navigate to http://tfs:8080/tfs/_diagnostics/EnableScriptDebugMode?disable=False

[image: Firebug error]

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was that the account being assigned to Microsoft Team foundation server application Pool (In IIS) did not have enough permission ...

I installed the TFS as a different user -- the administrator in my case, who has full privilege on system-- and it worked (note that I'm not sure however what specific permissions are required!).

Comment: I had the same error once I installed TFS 2015, and the solution was also to give local admin rights to the account TFS is running as...

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling IIS services resolved the problem